# how to style img in next.js

Tags: next.js, styled-components

```
import Image from 'next/image'

import styled from 'styled-components'

 <Grid container  >



            <Image className='logo'
              src="/logo-crazy-monkey-hd-png-download-800x11312396344-pngfind-crazy-hd-png-840_886.png"
              width={100}
              height={100}
            />



            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <UlFlex>
                <li><Link href="/categories" >CATEGORIES</Link></li>
                <li><Link href="/collections">COLLECTIONS </Link> </li>
                <li><Link href="resources" >RESOURCES</Link> </li>
              </UlFlex>
            </Grid>
```

> i what to style and to position imge in next.js i  what to to with
> style-component or if is there better way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap Components with `styled()` and style them, note: not all Components accept styles, check [extending Docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#extending-styles)

you can also give it `className` and style based on that, check
[Image Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image)

```
import Image from 'next/image'

import styled from 'styled-components'

const StyledImage = styled(Image)`
// your styles here
height: 100px; // example
width: 100px;
`

<Grid container>
    <StyledImage
      className="logo"
      src="/logo-crazy-monkey-hd-png-download-800x11312396344-pngfind-crazy-hd-png-840_886.png"
      width={100}
      height={100}
    />

    <Grid item xs={6}>
      <UlFlex>
        <li>
          <Link href="/categories">CATEGORIES</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link href="/collections">COLLECTIONS </Link>{" "}
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link href="resources">RESOURCES</Link>{" "}
        </li>
      </UlFlex>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>;
```